# About Django pk in urlpattern

Tags: python, django, url

I am new to Django, and I am reading one app on github:

https://github.com/rogargon/myrecommendations/blob/web2-html/myrestaurants/urls.py#L18

There is one urlpattern like

```
url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        RestaurantDetail.as_view(),
        name='restaurant_detail')
```

It revoke `RestaurantDetail` view, here: https://github.com/rogargon/myrecommendations/blob/master/myrestaurants/views.py#L36

```
class RestaurantDetail(DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'myrestaurants/restaurant_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['RATING_CHOICES'] = RestaurantReview.RATING_CHOICES
        return context
```

Here I know `pk` is set to one number indicating the id of restaurant, but in the html model, https://github.com/rogargon/myrecommendations/blob/master/myrestaurants/templates/myrestaurants/restaurant_detail.html, I didn't see any where using pk, but the page shows only the one restaurant. Could you how does `pk` work in this process? How the template know which restaurant I want to show? And why there is no return in this view?

```
 {% extends "myrestaurants/base.html" %}
{% block title %}MyRestaurants - {{ restaurant.name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<span vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Restaurant">

<h1>
    <span property="name">{{ restaurant.name }}</span>
    {% if user == restaurant.user %}
        (<a href="{% url 'myrestaurants:restaurant_edit' restaurant.id %}">edit</a>)
    {% endif %}
</h1>

<h2>Address:</h2>
<p>
    {{ restaurant.street }}, {{ restaurant.number }} <br/>
    {{ restaurant.zipcode }} {{ restaurant.city }} <br/>
    {{ restaurant.stateOrProvince }} ({{ restaurant.country }})
</p>

<h2>
    Dishes
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        (<a href="{% url 'myrestaurants:dish_create' restaurant.id %}">add</a>)
    {% endif %}
</h2>
<ul>
    {% for dish in restaurant.dishes.all %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'myrestaurants:dish_detail' restaurant.id dish.id %}">
            {{ dish.name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}<li>Sorry, no dishes for this restaurant yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<h2>Reviews</h2>
{% if restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all|length > 0 %}
<span rel="aggregateRating">
    <p typeof="AggregateRating">
        Average rating <span property="ratingValue">{{ restaurant.averageRating|stringformat:".1f" }}</span>
        {% with restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all|length as reviewCount %}
        from <span property="reviewCount">{{ reviewCount }}</span> review{{ reviewCount|pluralize }}
        {% endwith %}
    </p>
</span>
<ul rel="review">
    {% for review in restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all %}
        <li typeof="Review">
            <p rel="reviewRating" typeof="Rating">
                <span property="worstRating" content="{{ RATING_CHOICES.0.0 }}"></span>
                <span property="ratingValue">{{ review.rating }}</span> star{{ review.rating|pluralize }}
                {% with RATING_CHOICES|last as best %}
                <span property="bestRating" content="{{ best.0 }}"></span>
                {% endwith %}
            </p>
            <p property="description">{% if review.comment %}{{ review.comment }}{% endif %}</p>
            <p>Created by <span property="author">{{ review.user }}</span> on
                <span property="datePublished" content="{{ review.date|date:'Y-m-d' }}">{{ review.date }}</span></p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

</span>

<h3>Add Review</h3>
<form action="{% url 'myrestaurants:review_create' restaurant.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Message: <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="4"></textarea>
    <p>Rating:</p>
    <p>{% for rate in RATING_CHOICES %}
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ rate.0 }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ rate.1 }} star{{ rate.0|pluralize }}</label>
    <br/>{% endfor %}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Review" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
    Created by {{ restaurant.user }} on {{ restaurant.date }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So the url tag handler constructs the url for you - it takes your restaurant id as parameter and generates for you the url like `restaurants/1`, `restaurants/2` etc... Your <pk> tag is just part of regexp to let Django know which parameter to expect in restful call.

Comment: The url is  what I input in the address bar. And what do you mean by generate for me?

Comment: I mean url is a custom tag, it does some magic on your behalf so you don't have to explicitly hard-code it yourself. `{% url 'myrestaurants:dish_create' restaurant.id %}` is a custom tag.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're asking about ("How the template know which restaurant I want to show") is view behavior, not template behavior.

The template renderer gets passed a `restaurant` value by the view. The view has no (explicit) `return` because it's a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) - a subclass of `DetailView`, in particular. `DetailView` itself inherits standard methods that this view does not override to accept a PK parameter and load a particular instance.

You can read the source code for `DetailView` to get more of a sense of what's going on, if you like, eg https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py - but class-based views are a bit of an advanced topic, and not every project will even use them. I'd focus on other areas first.